# When ContentResolver.notifyChange() is called for a given URI, are ContentObservers observing descendent URIs of this URI notified?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

A hopefully straightforward question: When `ContentResolver.notifyChange()` is called for a given URI, are `ContentObserver`s observing *descendent* URIs of this URI notified?

E.g. Say I have a cursor setup to observer the URI of a specific resource:

```
 Uri uriA = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/orders/21");
 cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uriA);
```

I then notify the `ContentResolver` of a change to an ancestor of this URI (e.g. because I have deleted all orders):

```
 Uri uriB = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/orders");
 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uriB, null);
```

Would my `Cursor`, registered to observe `uriA`, be notified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After testing it, simple answer: yes.

Comment: I believe my answer is more accurate. Could you accept it or incorporate it into your own answer please? I have a feeling people often don't look past the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

It depends on how it was registered. If the `ContentObserver` was registered with the `notifyForDescendents` argument set as true, then yes. Otherwise no.

The registration is done through the method 
[`ContentResolver#registerContentObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver)):

```
void registerContentObserver (Uri uri, boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)
```